# Is it possible to make cucumber test fail?

Tags: java, cucumber, automated-tests, assertions

The piece of code I have below compares two list. 
In my step I use an if statement to check if the `destinationList` is empty, if so the test is correct and the cucumber steps should proceed.

However if the else statement is reached is there a way I can cause the cucumber test to fail? `

```
if (destinationList.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("This report is correct");

} else {
     System.out.println("This report is incorrect.");
     System.out.println("This list conatains the expected values of the report and their locations:");
     System.out.println("expected = "+sourceList);
     System.out.println("This list contains the actual value from this report and their locations:");
     System.out.println("actual = "+destinationList);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use JUnit as your test framework? If so then use

```
fail("Reason of fail")
```

This is a static method from class Assert
http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html

Comment: Or, rather than putting `fail` in an if statement, you could simply use `Assert.assertTrue(destinationList.isEmpty());`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. 
I had first tried `assert fail` which wasn't working.

The correct syntax turned out to be `Assert.fail();` which I included at the bottom of my else statement.